# Transmit default function parameters with Babel

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm using `stage-0` Babel preset to be able to use expressions like `myMethod = () => { /* code here */ }` like a class methods. Since I started to use this feature with `stage-0` preset, my projects stopped working at `iOS < 10` because of output code contains default function parameters `function myFunc(a, b = 0) { /*code here*/ }`

Is any ways here to configure Babel to transmit my code into lower standarts?

my webpack babel loader config:

`presets: ["es2015", "stage-0", "react"]`

P. S. Before I started to use `stage-0` everything was OK, babel loader config was the same without the `stage-0`.

---

### UPD:

Especially for Sulthan, code that generates an error

```
Component.prototype.has = function(key, opts, includeDefault = false) {
    var i18n = this.props.i18n;
    // Forth argument is the locale that should be used  
    // We can't use the active one because of the SSR and shared I18n state   
    // Also, we need to observe i18n.locale to detect changes, so this is useful    
    return I18n.has(key, opts, includeDefault, i18n.locale);  
};
```

The error is:

```
SyntaxError: 
    Unexpected token '='. 
    Expected a ')' or a ',' after a parameter declaration. /bundle.js:950
```

I'll repeat, that this part of code generated by Babel as a result of transmitting a code of, obviously, `i18n` library.

Comment: Default parameter values are part of `es2015`.

Comment: @Sulthan yea, therefore I'm telling about Babel.

Comment: You will have to add an example (minimal, compilable) of code that does not work.

Comment: @Sulthan whole bundle doesn't work. It throws an error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '='. Expected a ')' or a ',' after a parameter declaration. ` at `bundle.js:950`, and this error refers to a part of code generating by Babel

Comment: Turn off minify/uglify and add the code that triggers the error and the its transpiled version. This is probably a bug in your code and we cannot help you if you don't add it.

Comment: @Sulthan well, I just updated the post for your request

Comment: I have tried your code with the given presets and there are no default parameters in the transpiled code so I suppose you have a problem in your build. Maybe one of your files is not transpiled.

Comment: @Sulthan that's the point! That's an essence of my question, because, obviously, Babel doesn't work correctly with my config.

Comment: Check whether you don't have an `ignore` pattern in your config that would make a file to be skipped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, guys, the problem was that one of my node_modules was harmony, and my Babel config excluded whole `node_modules` catalogue.

```
loader: 'babel-loader',
exclude: /node_modules/,
query: {
  presets: ["es2015", "stage-0", "react"],
  plugins: ["transform-class-properties"]
}
```

I removed `exclude: /node_modules/,` from config and now it works perfectly!